# Using **kwargs on super() gives me Attribute Error

Tags: python, super, keyword-argument

Just trying to create a simple toy example to calculate the surface area of a pyramid:

```
class Rectangle:
    def __init__(self, length, width, **kwargs):
        self.length = length
        self.width = width
        #super().__init__(**kwargs)
    def area(self):
        return self.length * self.width
    def perim(self):
        return 2 * (self.length + self.width)

class Square(Rectangle):
    def __init__(self, length, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(length = length, width = length, **kwargs)

class Triangle:
    def __init__(self, base, height, **kwargs):
        self.base = base
        self.height = height
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
    def tri_area(self):
        return 0.5 * self.base * self.height

class Pyramid(Square, Triangle):
    def __init__(self, base, slant, **kwargs):
        kwargs["height"] = slant
        kwargs["length"] = base
        super().__init__(base = base, **kwargs)

    def surf_area(self):
        return super().area() + 4 * super().tri_area()

p = Pyramid(2,4)
p.surf_area()
```

But this gives me an error of

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-154-d97bd6ab2312> in <module>
      1 p = Pyramid(2,4)
----> 2 p.surf_area()

<ipython-input-153-457095747484> in surf_area(self)
      6 
      7     def surf_area(self):
----> 8         return super().area() + 4 * super().tri_area()

<ipython-input-151-8b1d4ef9dca9> in tri_area(self)
      5         super().__init__(**kwargs)
      6     def tri_area(self):
----> 7         return 0.5 * self.base * self.height

AttributeError: 'Pyramid' object has no attribute 'base'
```

The online resources don't seem to give much of a conceptual understanding of **kwargs too well (or they're written in too much a labrintyine manner for a beginner). Does this somehow have to do with the fact that **kwargs as an iterable need to be exhausted completely before going to the next call?

Comment: `class Pyramid(Square, Triangle)` - that doesn't make sense. A pyramid isn't a square, and it isn't a triangle.

Comment: Well... yes. You're right. However, I just created this toy example for learning's sake. A pyramid DOES have sides of a square and triangles, though.

Comment: i don't see why you're mixing kwargs into the issue here. plain and simple, `self.base` doesn't exist for pyramid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can sort of understand why you'd be confused. The main trick to realise is this: absolute bottom line, `kwargs` is not something magical. It is just a dictionary holding key value pairs. If a call requires more positional arguments than provided, it can look into keyword arguments and accept some values. However, kwargs does not invoke some magic that associates all names provided as a `self.<some_name_here>` .

So, first to just get a visual understanding of what's going on, what you should do when you don't understand a piece of code is making sure it runs how you think it does. Let's add a couple print statements and see what's happening.

Version 1:

```
class Rectangle:
    def __init__(self, length, width, **kwargs):
        self.length = length
        self.width = width
        print(f"in rectangle. length = {self.length}, width = {self.width}")
    def area(self):
        return self.length * self.width


class Square(Rectangle):
    def __init__(self, length, **kwargs):
        print("in square")
        super().__init__(length = length, width = length, **kwargs)

class Triangle:
    def __init__(self, base, height, **kwargs):
        print("in triangle")
        self.base = base
        self.height = height
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
    def tri_area(self):
        return 0.5 * self.base * self.height

class Pyramid(Square, Triangle):
    def __init__(self, base, slant, **kwargs):
        print("in pyramid")
        kwargs["height"] = slant
        kwargs["length"] = base
        super().__init__(base = base, **kwargs)

    def surf_area(self):
        print(f"area : {super().area()}")
        print(f"tri_area : {super().tri_area()}")
        return super().area() + 4 * super().tri_area()

p = Pyramid(2,4)
p.surf_area()
```

Output:

```
in pyramid
in square
in rectangle. length = 2, width = 2
area : 4
#and then an error, note that it occurs when calling super().tri_area()
#traceback removed for brevity.
AttributeError: 'Pyramid' object has no attribute 'base'
```

I suspect this already breaks some assumptions you had about how the code runs. *Notice that the triangle's init was never called*. But let's get rid of the parts that work fine, and add an additional print statement. I will also take the liberty of calling it with a different value for first argument, something that pops out easier.

Version 2:

```
class Rectangle:
    def __init__(self, length, width, **kwargs):
        self.length = length
        self.width = width
        print(f"in rectangle. length = {self.length}, width = {self.width}")
        print(f"kwargs are: {kwargs}")


class Square(Rectangle):
    def __init__(self, length, **kwargs):
        print("in square")
        super().__init__(length = length, width = length, **kwargs)

class Triangle:
    def __init__(self, base, height, **kwargs):
        print("in triangle")
        self.base = base
        self.height = height
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
    def tri_area(self):
        return 0.5 * self.base * self.height

class Pyramid(Square, Triangle):
    def __init__(self, base, slant, **kwargs):
        print("in pyramid")
        kwargs["height"] = slant
        kwargs["length"] = base
        super().__init__(base = base, **kwargs)

    def surf_area(self):
        print(f"tri_area : {super().tri_area()}")
        return super().tri_area()

p = Pyramid(10000,4)
p.surf_area()
```

Output:

```
in pyramid
in square
in rectangle. length = 10000, width = 10000
kwargs are: {'base': 10000, 'height': 4}
#error with traceback
AttributeError: 'Pyramid' object has no attribute 'base'
```

Bottom line: the kwargs holds a key with the name base, but this has no relation to `self.base`. However, my recommendation is to get rid of the whole class structure, and spend some time playing around with any basic function, get rid of the extra stuff.

Say, a demonstration:

```
def some_func(a, b, **kwargs):
    print(a, b)
    print(kwargs)

some_func(1, 2)
some_func(1, 2, c=42)
some_func(a=1, c=42, b=2)

def other_func(a, b, **look_at_me):
    print(a, b)
    print(look_at_me)

other_func(1, 2)
other_func(1, 2, c=42)
other_func(a=1, c=42, b=2)
```

These two chunks produce the same outputs. No magic here.
Output:

```
1 2
{}
1 2
{'c': 42}
1 2
{'c': 42}
```

When you added the classes into the mix, and inheritance, there's too many things happening at once. It is easier to miss what happens, so it's a good idea to use smaller code samples.